# Is a quotient of group schemes well defined?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, group-schemes

I will first define the notions of exact,surjective for group schemes and then ask my question.

Let $B$ and $C$ be fppf group schemes over S. The book I am reading defines a homomorphism $f:B\to C$ over $S$ to be surjective if for every $S$-scheme $T$ and element $c \in C(T)$, there is an fppf morphism $T'\to T$ such that the image of $c$ in $C(T')$ is the image of some $b\in B(T')$.

Call a sequence of fppf group schemes $A\to B\to C$ exact at $B$ if the composition is the trivial homomorphism and the induced homomorphism $A\to \ker(g)$ is surjective. If $A$ is the kernel of $B\to C$, then the book defines the quotient $B/A$ to be $C$.

**Question:**

Is this well defined? That is, if $f:B\to C$ and $g:B\to D$ are two surjective homomorphisms such that $\ker(f) \cong \ker(g)$ over $B$, does this imply that $C\cong D$ so that the relevant square commutes?

**My attempt:**

It suffices to show that for all affine schemes $T$, there is a functorial bijection $C(T) \to D(T)$.

If I define $\hat T$ to be the inverse limit of fppf maps $T'\to T$, then since for locally finite presentation schemes, it's functor of points commutes with taking direct limits of rings, I can show that there is a bijection $C(\hat T) \to D(\hat T)$.

I don't think this is enough to show that $C\cong D$ however...

Comment: Are you having difficulty showing injectivity or surjectivity?

Comment: I am not entirely sure how to even define the map $C(T) \to D(T)$.

Comment: Maybe it would help for you to show that if $f:A\to B$ is a surjection then $B\cong A/\ker f$ is an isomorphism where $\ker f$ is defined as usual ($T\mapsto \ker f(T)$) and the quotient is the quotient fppf sheaf--the fppf sheafification of $T\mapsto A(T)/\ker f(T)$.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks, I will try and prove that.